# fit vs fit_transform in pipeline

Tags: python-3.x, scikit-learn, pipeline

In this page https://www.kaggle.com/baghern/a-deep-dive-into-sklearn-pipelines

It calls `fit_transfrom` for tranforming the data as follows:

```
from sklearn.pipeline import FeatureUnion

feats = FeatureUnion([('text', text), 
                      ('length', length),
                      ('words', words),
                      ('words_not_stopword', words_not_stopword),
                      ('avg_word_length', avg_word_length),
                      ('commas', commas)])

feature_processing = Pipeline([('feats', feats)])
feature_processing.fit_transform(X_train)
```

While during training with feature processing, it only uses `fit` then `predict`

```
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier

pipeline = Pipeline([
    ('features',feats),
    ('classifier', RandomForestClassifier(random_state = 42)),
])

pipeline.fit(X_train, y_train)

preds = pipeline.predict(X_test)
np.mean(preds == y_test)
```

The question is, is the `fit` doing the transformation on `X_train` (as what is achieved by `transform`, since we are not calling `fit_transform` here) for second case?

Answer (score 3):

`sklearn-pipeline` has some nice features. It perform several task in a very clean way. We define our `features`, its `transformation` and `list of classifiers`, we want to perform, all in one function.

In the first step of this

```
pipeline = Pipeline([
    ('features',feats),
    ('classifier', RandomForestClassifier(random_state = 42)),
])
```

you have defined the features's name and its transformation function(that is incorporated in `feat`), in second step, you have defined the classifier's name and classifier classifier.

Now while calling `pipeline.fit`, it first fit features and transform it, then fit the classifier on the transformed features. So, it does some steps for us. More you can [check-here](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/7389dba/sklearn/pipeline.py#L239)